# 1950s or 1960s movie about an expedition to a living planet

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie on TV in the US in about 1971 or 1972.  I'm pretty sure that the movie was older than that, though.  My impression now is that it could have been made in the 60s or late 50s, not sure whether it was B&W or colorized.  I was only about 5 or 6 years old at the time, and I'm not completely sure.

The was a rocket expedition to another planet.  I'm pretty sure it was in our solar system, possibly a 'counter-earth', or a wandering planet.  The planet turned out to be a large living organism. They landed and sent a party into it.  I remember the inside having a lot of vine- or tentacle-like things hanging from the ceilings.  They may have been red and green in color.  I remember that it was dangerous inside but I'm not sure what the danger was.  As they were fleeing back to the ship, one of the party, I think an older scientist-type, gets injured and volunteers (or is forced) to be left behind so as not to slow down the escape.  I remember feeling very sad when I saw that part.

Comment: Not exactly on mark, but maybe "Journey to the Seventh Planet"? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056127/

The scientists do go underground where there are vine like things.  Baddie turns out to be a big brain and not the whole planet.

Comment: @BlueGI I don't think so.  The plot summaries on IMDB and Wikipedia don't align with my memories, but it's definitely from the right time period and has the right general look.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"War Between the Planets"(Italian;1966)?

Italian title:"Il pianeta errante"

I've already answered this question and it was accepted, but the poster was not completely sure about my answer and some parts of the movie didn't seem familiar, so then I found this movie and saw that it had an almost identical plot and it was from the same director! The director was Antonio Margheriti, but he's listed in the credits as "Anthony Dawson". It was common for Italian directors of the time to use English sounding names in the American release versions of their films. This movie was part of the Gamma-One series of films and was preceded by "Wild, Wild Planet"(1965).

I posted the full movie from YouTube below. You can see the 'red tubes' you described at 1:00:20, the scientist type sacrificing his life so the others can escape at 1:09:00, and the funeral for this man at 1:15:00.

Comment: This seems more like it than the other.  The hacking at the arteries, and the way they heal back, the checkered pattern on the one helmet, the slow pace in general, the pools and mist, all of those seem familiar.  Nice work!  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks LAK, I'm glad I spotted this one, and it does look like the better of the two.

Answer (score 5):

"Battle of the Worlds"(1961)?

Here is the entire movie from YouTube. If you go to 1:22:00, you will see an astronaut saying goodbye to the old scientist (played by Claude Raines) as they head back to earth.

And at 1:22:42 you can see the scientist's dog eagerly awaiting his return. I can see why it would make someone sad! Also the interior of the planet has reddish tubes hanging down everywhere and the runaway planet is controlled by an artificial alien brain? Oh well, it seems to match the story points you listed.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, but I don't remember a dog.  Definitely the right kind of look, though.  I also don't remember the flying saucer fight, that definitely would have stood out in my mind.  I'll watch the entire thing tomorrow, though, to be sure.  Thanks!

Comment: This may indeed be it.  The stuff about the planet being a danger to earth sounds familiar, and the hanging tubes may be the imagery I'm remembering.  I think I watched it when I was home sick from school, so my memories might be unreliable.

Comment: I watched it and I'm not 100% sure, but it's close enough that I'll accept this answer!